# Finding path using Cypher queries in neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm using neo4j 2.1.2 version community edition. I have one issue in finding the path which i'm looking for using cypher.
I have data in csv file and loaded the data into neo4j database using LOAD CSV option.
The data looks like below:

Query Used:

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:C:\\WorkingFolder\\Neo4j\\EDGE_Graph_POC\\newdata\\test.csv " as file
MERGE (role:Role {Role:file.RoleName})
MERGE (u:User {User:file.UserName})
Merge (c:Country {Country:file.Country})
MERGE (s:State {State: file.State})
MERGE (a:Address {Address:file.Address})
MERGE (comp:Company {Company: file.Company})

MERGE (u)-[:Has]->(role)-[:GivenAccess_To]->(a)-[:Present_IN]->(s)-[:Belongs_TO]->(c)- [:Comes_Under]->(comp)
```

Data file Used:

[image]

Resultant Graph:
[image]

Then I merged two addresses into a single Address with a relationship as below and given access to a User called 'Susan Smith' to access the newly merged address which is shown below:
Graph:
[image]

**Issue I'm facing:**
Here If someone wants to see the merged address which belongs to which country and state and also to see which user is given access.Also in the above image i have marked the path which i'm looking for.

The query i used to get the path is :

```
match path = (x)-[r1:Merged_TO]->(y)
with y
match path1  = (u:User)-[:Has]->()-[:GivenAccess_To]->(y)-[:Present_IN]->(s)-[:Belongs_TO]->(b)-[:Comes_Under]->(comp)
return path1;
```

**Output Graph :**
[image]

But here i'm supposed to get only one user called `Susen Smith` but getting all the users who are attached to `Publisher` node. So how can i get that information.

Expected Graph is : 
[image]
`**NOTE :**` Here i do not want to pass the User name. wheneven i enter the Merged_TO relationship, i should get the  new merged node and user information who is supposed to access that node.

How can i do it?

Answer (score 1):

I believe that your model has been setup to give all Publishers access to the Address rather than a specific Person.

In your original import this occurs in the fragment:

```
(u)-[:Has]->(role)-[:GivenAccess_To]->(a)
```

Maybe it should have been:

```
(u)-[:HAS]->(role), (u)-[:GivenAccess_To]->(a)
```

This would make the access not dependent on the role but on the User. You can then use your query with one minor adjustment (but it will not contain the role).

```
MATCH (x)-[r1:Merged_TO]->(y)
WITH y
MATCH path1  = (u:User)-[:GivenAccess_To]->(y)-[:Present_IN]->(s)-[:Belongs_TO]->(b)-[:Comes_Under]->(comp)
return path1;
```

**Update: After Roles clarified.**
If it is the case that a User does not have access to an Address, and that a Role does not have access to an Address, but that it is a User in a particular Role that does, then you will have to add a further level of indirection. Something like:

```
...
MERGE (u)-[:IN_USER_ROLE]->(ur:UserRole)<-[:HAS_ROLE]-(role)
(ur)-[:GivenAccess_To]->(a)
...
```

Now to get the lot back you can use something like:

```
MATCH (x)-[r1:Merged_TO]->(y)
WITH y
MATCH path1  = (u:User)-[:IN_USER_ROLE]->(ur:UserRole)-[:GivenAccess_To]->(y)-[:Present_IN]->(s)-[:Belongs_TO]->(b)-[:Comes_Under]->(comp)
MATCH (ur)<-[:HAS_ROLE]-(role)
return path1, role;
```

Comment: The important thing is that you can see in your screenshots that the yellow nodes are connected to the red nodes. It sounds like you want the blue nodes to be connected to the red nodes.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. You are right. While modelling itself i would have done like whatever you told. Now its perfectly fine. Thanks again. I will let you know if i face some issues there in finding paths

Comment: Even i tried the solution given by you but when i tried to get the Role information for that particular user, again getting all the roles for that user. but i wanted only one role which is assigned to the user 'Susan Smith' for the merged address. Hope you understand the scenario. so how can i do it?

Comment: Well, whilst I would suggest breaking your query down into separate paths to avoid really expensive traversals, is what you want to achieve achieved by starting from: `MATCH path1  = (role)<-[:HAS]-(u:User)-[:GivenAccess_To]->(y)-[:Present_IN]->(s)-[:Belongs_TO]->(b)-[:Comes_Under]->(comp)`.

Comment: Yes, the query looks fine but in case if the User `Susane` has more than two Roles say `Publisher`,`Editor`,`Admin` and then if only Admin Role is given to the newly created address. Then how the query is going to be? If i use the above query it gives all the roles for the user susane for the newly merged node

Comment: I see, so Susan should not have `GivenAccess_To`, and Publisher should not have `GivenAccess_To`, but rather SusanThePublisher should have `GivenAccess_To`. So it is a combination of Users/Roles that governs access?

Comment: Yes, Both User and Roles will play their role here as apart of security.

Comment: In the above query you have mentioned `(ur:UserRole)`. What is that actually? I did not get that node exactly.

Comment: If you want both the User **and** the Role to form the basis of the `GivenAccess_To` you will have to create a Node that represents the concept of the User in a particular Role. Not very imaginatively I called it UserRole.